# Get Perfect Full screen mode in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fullscreen, android-statusbar

I am using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"` inside `application` tag of `AndroidManifest.xml` to get full screen mode for my application. Its working good as well. Picture given below.
[image]

Now the problem is that, if we slide down from top most area of app screen, then the status bar is getting visible. Look at the below picture.
[image]

How to rid of this scenario and get perfect full screen mode?

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't if you could.

Comment: I should! if I can :/

Comment: If you check every game app, you will notice the same. You should have some control to exit out of your app or to check notification at any instant irrespective of application